# Is it safe for a client to ask the server if the user is logged in using AJAX?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-web-api

I want my system to display a "session expired" message if the user was idle.

What security risks am I facing if I make an AJAX call each T seconds/minutes to an API endpoint which checks if the user is authenticated or not?

```
/// <summary>
/// Used to check if the user was idle and the session expired.
/// </summary>
[Authorize]
public class IdleController : ApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Used by the system to check if the session expired while the user was idle.
    /// If the user is not logged in anymore because of a terminated session, the AuthorizeAttribute will not pass the request to this method.
    /// An HTTP 401 response will be returned, indicating the expiration of the session.
    /// If the session is still active an HTTP 200 will be returned with a null value response.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Always null.</returns>
    public object GetCheck()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

```js
var idleTimeout;

function StartIdleCheckTimeout()
{
    idleTimeout = setTimeout(CheckIdle, 60000);
}

function CheckIdle()
{
    $.ajax("Api/Idle/Check", {
        statusCode: {
            200: ResetIdleCheckTimeout,
            401: OnUserIdle
        }
    });
}

function ResetIdleCheckTimeout()
{
    clearTimeout(idleTimeout);

    StartIdleCheckTimeout();
}

function OnUserIdle()
{
    alert("Su sesión ha expirado. Por favor ingresa nuevamente.");

    RedirectTo("/");
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Shy.

Comment: I would remove on client side the cookie after a specific time an renew the time of this cookie with each User Request.

Comment: re: security risk - it depends what information you are passing in the request and how. I think you need to be a bit more specific about your actual implementation.

Comment: Will update my question with some code...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have any security risks except usual ones for web. But you will have a lot of headache with async requests in js, it's a bit tricky to handle correctly such requests when you have to use them instead of permanent connections.

Answer (score 0):

There is no serious security risk about that. One of the most important things about those kind of stuff is storing sensitive information on server-side session. When you need to access one of those information, such as logged-in timestamp, you need to access this through session ID.

Answer (score 0):

The risk is that your AJAX request will act as a "keep alive", so the session will never expire if your site is open in the browser and internet connectivity is active.

This could mean that the security timeout of your application would no-longer protect against local attackers accessing a user's unlocked machine (whether this is a problem in your target environments is for you to decide).

You could time the session client-side though, and call your logout handler should the user not move the mouse or press the keyboard on your app for a certain amount of time. This however increases complexity, which tends to reduce security.

Note that [Forms Authentication by default does not expire session server-side upon logout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout.aspx).

> Calling the SignOut method only removes the forms authentication cookie. The Web server does not store valid and expired authentication tickets for later comparison. This makes your site vulnerable to a replay attack if a malicious user obtains a valid forms authentication cookie. To improve security when using a forms authentication cookie, you should do the following:
>
> - Use absolute expiration for forms authentication cookies by setting the SlidingExpiration property to false. This limits the window in which a hijacked cookie can be replayed.
> - Only issue and accept authentication cookies over Secure Sockets Layer (SSL), by setting the RequireSSL property to true and by running the entire Web site under SSL. Setting the RequireSSL property to true ensures that ASP.NET will never send an authentication cookie to the browser over a non-SSL connection; however, the client might not honor the secure setting on the cookie. This means the client might send the forms authentication cookie over a non-SSL connection, thus leaving it vulnerable to hijack. You can prevent a client from sending the forms authentication cookie in the clear by running the entire Web site under SSL.
> - Use persistent storage on the server to record when a user logs out of the Web site, and then use an application event such as PostAuthenticateRequest event to determine whether the current user was authenticated with forms authentication. If the user was authenticated with forms authentication, and if the information in persistent storage indicates the user is logged out, immediately clear the authentication cookie and redirect the browser back to the login page. After a successful login, update storage to reflect that the user is logged in. When you use this method, your application must track the logged-in status of the user, and must force idle users to log out.

Therefore you should implement these recommendations in order to increase security.

Comment: What if the AJAX call is made to an ApiController and not a regular MVC controller?
Will it still reset the session's timeout?

Comment: Yes, I can't see why it wouldn't because the ApiController uses the same authorisation method so the authentication timeout should be extended should sliding expiration be enabled.